# Converting a SQLServer to Linq Query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I would like to know what is the correct way to convert this query to LINQ.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ( CONVERT(date,FechaCreacion)) FROM Tabla
where ID = 4
order by CONVERT(date,FechaCreacion) desc 
OFFSET     (0 * 20) ROWS    
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
```

With this query it brings me this data:

```
 1. 2021-03-16
 2. 2021-03-15
 3. 2021-03-14
 4. 2021-03-13
 5. 2021-03-11
 6. 2021-03-09
 7. 2021-03-02
 8. 2021-02-28
 9. 2021-02-25
 10. 2021-02-24
 11. 2021-02-23
 12. 2021-02-22
 13. 2021-02-21
 14. 2021-02-19
 15. 2021-02-10
 16. 2020-11-30
 17. 2020-10-05
 18. 2020-02-18
```

LINQ:

```
var query = (from sp in esquema.Tabla
                                 where sp.ID== 4
                                 orderby DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sp.FechaCreacion) descending
                                 select new
                                 {
                                    fechacreacion = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sp.FechaCreacion)
                                 }
                                 ).Skip(0* 20).Take(20).ToList().Distinct();
```

With LINQ it brings me less data than the query made directly in SQL Server

```
 1. 2021-03-16
 2. 2021-03-15
 3. 2021-03-14
 4. 2021-03-13
 5. 2021-03-11
 6. 2021-03-09
 7. 2021-03-02
 8. 2021-02-28
 9. 2021-02-25
 10. 2021-02-24
 11. 2021-02-23
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not in English.

Comment: This is an English language site. Either translate or try https://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say the DISTINCT clause in the SQL is executing *earlier* than the one in the Linq (i.e. before the 20 row OFFSET).

Answer (score 0):

You have applied `Distinct` to already paginated result. That's why result is different.

```cs
var query = 
    from sp in esquema.Tabla
    where sp.ID == 4
    orderby DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sp.FechaCreacion) descending
    select new
    {
        fechacreacion = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sp.FechaCreacion)
    };

var query = query
    .Distinct()
    .Skip(0 * 20)
    .Take(20)
    .ToList();
```